# How do you access nested objects in Swift?

Tags: oop, swift, realm

Below is the readout of println(newArticle)

I am able to access a paragraph by using newArticle.paragraphs[0]. How can access sentences[0]? (or is that even what I should be trying to access?)

I have tried newArticle.paragraphs[0].sentences[0], but I get an error that says 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'sentences'.

```
Article {
    title = test;
    viewed = 0;
    paragraphs = RLMArray <0x7c986ec0> (
    [0] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x7c999da0> (

    );
        paragraphContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    ;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = RLMArray <0x7c9b4af0> (
        [0] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [1] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [2] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [3] <Maximum depth exceeded>
    );
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    },
    [1] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x7c9b7dc0> (

    );
        paragraphContent = 2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    ;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = RLMArray <0x7c9b6720> (
        [0] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [1] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [2] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [3] <Maximum depth exceeded>
    );
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    },
    [2] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x7c9b6880> (

    );
        paragraphContent = 3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = RLMArray <0x7c9b66c0> (
        [0] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [1] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [2] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [3] <Maximum depth exceeded>
    );
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    },
    [3] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x7c9b6820> (

    );
        paragraphContent = ;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = RLMArray <0x7c9b9650> (
        [0] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [1] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [2] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
        [3] <Maximum depth exceeded>
    );
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    }
);
    articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
    dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
}
```

This is what I see when I println(newArticle.paragraphs[0].description)

```
Paragraph {
    sentences = RLMArray <0x78f7b920> (

);
    paragraphContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
;
    article = Article {
    title = test;
    viewed = 0;
    paragraphs = RLMArray <0x78f7b570> (
    [0] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x78f7bdf0> (

    );
        paragraphContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    ;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = <Maximum depth exceeded>;
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    },
    [1] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x78f7c720> (

    );
        paragraphContent = 2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    ;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = <Maximum depth exceeded>;
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    },
    [2] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x78f7c1f0> (

    );
        paragraphContent = 3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = <Maximum depth exceeded>;
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    },
    [3] Paragraph {
        sentences = RLMArray <0x78f7f240> (

    );
        paragraphContent = ;
        article = Article {
        title = test;
        viewed = 0;
        paragraphs = <Maximum depth exceeded>;
        articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
    2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
    3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
        dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
    };
    }
);
    articleContent = 1最初，上帝创造了天地。
2大地混沌苍茫，深渊的表面一片黑暗。上帝发出的动力运行在水面上。
3上帝说:“要有光。”光就出现了。4上帝看光是好的。上帝把光暗分开了。5上帝称光为“昼”，称暗为“夜”。过了晚上，到了早晨，是第一日。;
    dateAdded = 2014-12-16 15:12:29 +0000;
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the object you are pulling out of paragraphs to a Paragraph. Swift only knows that the object is an AnyObject and AnyObject doesn't have a "sentences" property, so it complains.

something like

```
let paragraph = newArticle.paragraphs[0] as Paragraph
println(paragraph.sentences[0])
```

or, to be safer,

```
if let paragraph = newArticle.paragraphs[0] as? Paragraph {
    println(paragraph.sentences[0])
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there away to iterate through this structure so that I can print out all the sentences in all the paragraphs of the entire article? I can make another another question instead, but at least help me ask the right question.

Comment: Take a look at the control flows section of the documentation and you will find details about looping structures: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html